# Compare and Search String Value in Two Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table: t1

[image]

Table: t2

[image]

I want to write a SQL query to compare the column username in the two tables and return only unmatched value as below:

ID: 5        Username:    Leanghour
ID: 4        Username:      Nimol

Anyone can help me

Comment: *and return only unmatched value* Define matching criteria completely. Without referring to definite values. *as below* ?? Why `id` in desired output does not match to those in source data?

Comment: Ohh sorry, let me correct.

Comment: Could you help me, sir?

Comment: No, you have not provided complete matching criteria definition.

Comment: I want to return only unmatched value only by using column username to compare. It should be returned only: Nimol and leanghour.

Comment: There is some `t1.username` value. There is some another `t2.username` value. We do not see the values itself, we only know that they're assigned. Provide an expression which uses these two values and returns either TRUE (they matches) or FALSE (they not matches). Or at least describe this expression logic.

Comment: Hi Sir, this is the query to use to find the matches value from both columns: SELECT t1.username, t2.username FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.username LIKE concat('%', t1.username)
WHERE t1.username REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' ORDER BY t1.username;

Comment: It's return: Kaka,  Leap Kaka, Mala and Mr. Mala

Comment: I don't know how to query the remaining unmatched.